# Websocket performance vs socket.io performance for a flutter app

Tags: websocket, flutter, socket.io

I am going to make a chat app in flutter, but I am consfusing to choose between Websocket and socket.io.

A little bit I know about socket.io which it is a library and event driven.
But i dont have any idea about websocket.

My expection is, **it should work very fast, broadcast messages, room creation capabilities.**

Answer (score 1):

As I think websocket is a technology base on tcp protocol and socket.io is a library of websocket.

so here websocket may be works fast there is less options
socket.io have a lot of capabilites like broadcasting, namespace and room which as i know websocket does not have

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how use socket.io in flutter without using plugin, because I love to use directly